# How can I control +12V motors with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, transistors

I have 3.3V control signals and I wish to control 12v motors. This can be done simply with a PNP power transistor with the motor on the positive side on the collector, but the motor I am using has two positive (one per direction) connections and one negative so I can't draw current through the motor but need to provide 12V on the chosen input signal.

Using https://www.falstad.com/circuit/ I have found that I can use an NPN attached to the base of a PNP:

[image]

I don't understand what the NPN is adding here.  Can this be done with one transistor? Does it have a name such that I can see if I can get  a breakout board with many of these on it.

Answer (score 0):

The NPN inverts the logic.  With just a PNP a low signal turns your circuit "on" while a high shuts it off.  By adding the NPN in front of it, you reverse this so a high signal turns it "on".

If you are controlling this via software you write and/or control, I hardly see the point...unless you have only one I/O to work with.  If that is the case, you can have a circuit like this in parallel with a single PNP circuit.  This way one I/O will energize one of the two inputs depending on whether it is high or low.

Answer (score 0):

A more common method for doing high side control is presented below.  I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but maybe it'll put you on a better path for controlling the motor you have.

Adjust the voltage divider to make the Vgs of the PMOS to fit the FET that you choose.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZIhik.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>